# How to set a custom environment key in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Creating a custom environment key works, but if I wish to set the value in a view, XCODE doesn't allow it. But the predefined environment values can be set. What am I doing wrong?

```
struct ResetDefault: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: Bool = false
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var resetDefault: Bool {
        get { self[ResetDefault.self] }
        set { self[ResetDefault.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct ResetView: View {
    @Environment(\.resetDefault) var reset
    var body: some View {
        Text("Reset").onAppear() {
            reset = true.        // Cannot assign to property: 'reset' is a get-only property
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `Environment` is used to pass values in `parent > child` direction, so value is set for usage. If you want to change *internal* of environment value then you need to wrap it somehow, possible variants are binding or reference type holder.

Here is an example of usage based on binding (similar to how .editMode and .presentationMode work)

```
struct TestResetEnv: View {
    @State private var isActive = false
    @State private var reset = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Current: \(reset ? "true" : "false")")
            Button("Go") { self.isActive.toggle() }
            if isActive {
                ResetView()
            }
        }.environment(\.resetDefault, $reset) // set for children as env!!
    }
}

struct ResetDefault: EnvironmentKey {
    static var defaultValue: Binding<Bool> = .constant(false)
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var resetDefault: Binding<Bool> {
        get { self[ResetDefault.self] }
        set { self[ResetDefault.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct ResetView: View {
    @Environment(\.resetDefault) var reset
    var body: some View {
        Text("Reset").onAppear() {
            self.reset.wrappedValue.toggle() // << change wrapped !!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you think of an example where you realistically would use such an editable environment value? I wonder if this shouldn't be almost always a property on a EnvironmentObject...

Comment: @RalfEbert, Realistic solution using this approach [SwiftUI - How to close the sheet view, while dismissing that view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60314365/12299030)

Comment: @RalfEbert, another one using reference type [SwiftUI how to change state on keyUp macOS event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61278596/12299030)

Comment: This solution compiles but doesn't work. The wrapped value is never set any differently from it's default.

Comment: Actually, correction: good solution, you have to remember to add : .environment(\.resetDefault, $reset)  (or else no warnings or errors,  but nothing happens)