# How to change app tint color (New SwiftUI life cycle app)?

Tags: swift, swiftui

What is the best way to change app tint color in a SwiftUI app?

It is powered by the new SwiftUI lifecycle so I do not have the option to perform self.?tintColor

Tried searching here but didn't find any way to do it in a SwiftUI lifecycle app.

Comment: You should ask a single question to be more focused and create a new one for your second one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `SceneDelegate.swift` where you create the window for your app you can set the tint color globally using the `tintColor` property of `UIWindow`

```
let contentView = ContentView()

if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
    window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
    self.window = window

    self.window?.tintColor = UIColor.red // Or any other color you want
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

**Edit**
After seeing that you want it for the new SwiftUI, you can create new EnvironmentKeys:

```swift
private struct TintKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: Color = Color.blue
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var tintColor: Color {
        get { self[TintKey.self] }
        set { self[TintKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
   
@main
struct YourApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environment(\.tintColor, Color.red)
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your views you would use it like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.tintColor) var tintColor
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .padding()
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                Text("Button")
            })
        }.accentColor(tintColor)       
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't use the SceneDelegate file since I use the new SwiftUI life cycle app (it contains a .app file which is the main file for the app).

Comment: Did you try setting `.accentColor(.red)` to the view in the Scene?

Comment: It doesn't work like tintColor. It just changes tint for the 1 view it is connected to, not the whole app like tintColor... Thanks for suggesting.

Comment: It is inherited from ancestors, but if you have many flows you can use en environment var  `@Environment(\.accentColor) var accentColor`

Comment: 'accentcolor' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Comment: Edited the answer with an example about how to create your custom environment key

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, I have returned to this project after abandoning it. When I try to set a new value, I get "Cannot assign to property: 'tintColor' is a get-only property". I tried to go by this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847041/how-to-set-a-custom-environment-key-in-swiftui, but not going well with color...

Answer (score 9):

This works without an `EnvironmentKey`, and propagates to all views in the app:

```
@main

struct MyApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .accentColor(.red) // pick your own color
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I find this to be the correct answer. The answer above by Itay may work but it's really not utilizing SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

Ariel,
In this implementation,
you can choose and use 'accentColor' throughout the entire application lifecycle. However, if you want to keep a value permanently,
you should think about a solution,
I hope you are a smart guy ...

```
 enum MyColor: Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    var id: String { UUID().uuidString }
    case blue, green, orange, pink, purple, red, yellow
    var currentColor: Color {
        switch self {
        case .blue:
            return .blue
        case .green:
            return .green
        case .orange:
            return .orange
        case .pink:
            return .pink
        case .purple:
            return .purple
        case .red:
            return .red
        case .yellow:
            return .yellow
        }
    }
}

final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published
    var isPresented = false
    @Published
    var myColor: MyColor = .blue
}

struct AppSettings: View {
    @ObservedObject
    var vm: ViewModel
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Picker("Current color", selection: $vm.myColor) {
                    ForEach(MyColor.allCases) { color in
                        Label(
                            title: {
                                Text(color.currentColor.description.capitalized)
                            }, icon: {
                                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                            })
                            .tag(color)
                            .foregroundColor(color.currentColor)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing:
                    Button(
                        action: {
                            vm.isPresented.toggle()},
                        label: {
                Text("Close")
            }))
            .navigationTitle("App settings")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject
    private var vm = ViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(
                action: {
                    vm.isPresented.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    VStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(Color.accentColor)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        Text("Settings")
                            .font(.title)
                    }
                })
        }
        .accentColor(vm.myColor.currentColor)
        .sheet(
            isPresented: $vm.isPresented) {
            AppSettings(vm: vm)
                .accentColor(vm.myColor.currentColor)
        }
    }
}
```