# SwiftUI globally changing an environment variable

Tags: swift, swiftui, environment-variables

I've integrated themes into my app using this [This idea](https://www.fabisevi.ch//2021/08/24/creating-slick-color-palette-apis/)

I have an `EnvironmentKey` that is used throughout the app:

```
private struct ColorThemeKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue = Color.Theme.system
//    static let defaultValue = Color.Theme.night
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var preferredColorTheme: Color.Theme {
        get {
            return self[ColorThemeKey.self]
        }
        set {
            self[ColorThemeKey.self] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

It works great by changing the default value and relaunching the app.

I'm new to `EnvironmentKey`'s and i'm struggling to figure out how to allow the user to change this. I have a list of available themes, but how to I overwrite the current them and set a new one that will take over immediately?

When I try to set a new theme like this, it tells me it's get only:

```
let newTheme = theme.theme
Environment(\.preferredColorTheme).wrappedValue = newTheme
```

Comment: You change it in view, consider this as example https://stackoverflow.com/a/61847419/12299030.

Comment: So I have the theme as a `State` in the root view and inject it using `.environment` but when several views down how do I change the state in the root for it to change?

Comment: I've created a Themes singleton and added it as an `envrionmentObject` and have it working. So I think I misunderstand how the `EnvironmentValues` is used.